# UIBarButtonItem image not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks, uibarbuttonitem

I have very strange problem. I'm initializing some UI elements inside completion block of AFNetworking, and only one of them (`UIBarButtonItem`) is not initializing. Here is my code which is placed in `viewDidLoad`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[m_httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     NSError* error;
     self.m_pointData = [NSJSONSerialization
                        JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                        options:kNilOptions
                        error:&error];

     [self InitializeFields];
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error in get point response: %@", error);
 }];

[operation start];
```

}

I do initialization inside InitializeFields and here is the code:

```
self.m_placeName.text = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"name"];

self.m_placeLocation.text = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"city"];

NSArray* comments = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"comments"];

const int commentsCount = [comments count];

self.m_commentsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", commentsCount];

self.m_scrollView.m_address.text = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"address"];
self.m_scrollView.m_email.text = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"email"];
self.m_scrollView.m_phone.text = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"tel"];
self.m_scrollView.m_link.text = [self.m_pointData objectForKey:@"website"];

self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_inactive.png"];
```

Only the last line – `self.m_rightBtn.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite_star_inactive.png"];` – does not work. When I'm moving it to `viewDidLoad` it works. Something with completion block, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2):

I can assume that this block is not in the main thread.
Try to do to this in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update button
    });
```

Also next assumption is that image hasn't  initialized while you're accessing it in block.
Add check:

```
if (!self.m_rightBtn.Image) {
    self.m_rightBtn.Image = [UIImage new];
}
```

Comment: Rest of UI controls work, there is no problem with main thread, completion block works there. Something wrong with bar button item image. Label texts etc work correctly.

Comment: Did you tru check for nil?

Comment: Yes @Roma, it's not nil.

Comment: If your AFNetworking code is in view did load try moving it to viewDidAppear. I now that it is bad approach but let's do it for the sake of expirement. I think that uiimage us not ready in viewdidload

Answer (score 1):

UI things are supposed to happen on the main thread, not on secondary threads (which completion blocks may be).

Do the UI stuff within this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // This block will be executed asynchronously on the main thread.
});
```

and all will be well.  There's more detail to be found [in this related question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205547/how-to-update-ui-in-a-task-completion-block).

Comment: Missed to say that completion block for AFNetworking works on main thread, AFNetworking guarantees that, also I've checked that.